# Enumerate the $m^n$ indexes of $m$ points along each axis of an $n$-dimensional space

Tags: elementary-number-theory, numerical-methods

This is a little programming problem where I need to enumerate, as $i=1,2,3,\ldots,m^n$, the sequences of coordinates
$$\begin{array}{rc}
 i=1\ldots m: & (1,1,...,1,1), (1,1,...,1,2), ..., (1,1,....,1,m)\\
 i=m+1\ldots 2m: & (1,1,...,2,1), (1,1,...,2,2), ..., (1,1,....,2,m)\\
      & \vdots\\
i=m^n-m+1\ldots m^n: & (m,m,...,m,1), (m,m,...,m,2), ..., (m,m,....,m,m)
 \end{array}$$
where each sequence has $n$ numbers.

So I need a programmable (preferably easily/straightforwardly programmable:) function $f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N^n$ that generates these sequences in the illustrated order as $i=1,\ldots,m^n$.
(Looks like maybe some recursion of the inverse pairing function, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function, but I can't see how to do that. And hopefully there's an easier way.)

**E d i t
------------------**
In case it's of any interest, below's the very short-and-easy **C** function
implementing @Haran's answer. Note that since this is **C**, my needed indices actually go from $0$ to $m-1$ rather than the $1$ to $m$ that I illustrated in the question above...

```
/*===========================================================================
 * Function:    clxcoord ( i, ndim, npts )
 * Purpose:     enumerates coordinates (x_1,x_2,...,x_ndim)
 *              from (0,0,...,0) to (npts-1,npts-1,...,npts-1)
 *              corresponding to i=0...npts^ndim-1
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Arguments:   i (I)           int containing 0...npts^ndim-1
 *              ndim (I)        int containing number of dimensions
 *              npts (I)        int containing number of pts along each axis
 * Returns:     (int *)         i^th sequence of coords (x_1,x_2,...,x_ndim)
 *                              or NULL for any error
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Notes:     o
 *======================================================================== */
/* --- entry point --- */
int *clxcoord ( int i, int ndim, int npts ) {
  static int xbuff[16][99];
  static int ibuff = 0;
  int    *xcoord = xbuff[ibuff];
  int    idim = 0;
  if ( ++ibuff >= 16 ) ibuff=0;
  for ( idim=0; idim<ndim; idim++ ) {
    xcoord[(ndim-1)-idim] = i%npts;
    i /= npts; }
  return ( xcoord );
  } /* --- end-of-function clxcoord() --- */
```

And here's the short snippet testing the function, followed by its output...

```
  if ( testnum == 3 ) {
    int *xcoord=NULL, *clxcoord();
    int ndim=3, maxcoord=4;
    int icoord=0,i=0, ncoords=(int)(pow((double)maxcoord,(double)ndim)+0.5);
    for ( icoord=0; icoord<ncoords; icoord++ ) {
      xcoord = clxcoord(icoord,ndim,maxcoord);
      printf(" icoord=%04d: (",icoord);
      for ( i=0; i<ndim; i++ )
        printf("%d%s",xcoord[i],(i<ndim-1?",":")\n")); }
    } /* --- end-of-if(testnum==3) --- */
 icoord=0000: (0,0,0)
 icoord=0001: (0,0,1)
 icoord=0002: (0,0,2)
 icoord=0003: (0,0,3)
 icoord=0004: (0,1,0)
 icoord=0005: (0,1,1)
 icoord=0006: (0,1,2)
 icoord=0007: (0,1,3)
 icoord=0008: (0,2,0)
 icoord=0009: (0,2,1)
 icoord=0010: (0,2,2)
 icoord=0011: (0,2,3)
 icoord=0012: (0,3,0)
 icoord=0013: (0,3,1)
 icoord=0014: (0,3,2)
 icoord=0015: (0,3,3)
 icoord=0016: (1,0,0)
 icoord=0017: (1,0,1)
...
 icoord=0047: (2,3,3)
 icoord=0048: (3,0,0)
 icoord=0049: (3,0,1)
 icoord=0050: (3,0,2)
 icoord=0051: (3,0,3)
 icoord=0052: (3,1,0)
 icoord=0053: (3,1,1)
 icoord=0054: (3,1,2)
 icoord=0055: (3,1,3)
 icoord=0056: (3,2,0)
 icoord=0057: (3,2,1)
 icoord=0058: (3,2,2)
 icoord=0059: (3,2,3)
 icoord=0060: (3,3,0)
 icoord=0061: (3,3,1)
 icoord=0062: (3,3,2)
 icoord=0063: (3,3,3)
```

Now, **...** if I can only get @Haran to do the rest of my work for me **:)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply convert $i-1$ to base $m$. Then, take convert all the digits (with leading $0s$) into a sequence of length $n$. Convert digits such as $A$ into $10$, $B$ into $11$ and so on. Finally, add $1$ to all the values in the sequence. This gives you the required.

Comment: Thanks, Haran. Wow, that was easy **>>now that you mention it<<** (P.S. I think you mean "sequence of length $n$").

Comment: @JohnForkosh Yes I did, thank you

Comment: @JohnOmielan I am considering the conversion to base $m$. Just wanted to convey that the values that are taken as digits must be converted to their base $10$ counterparts.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Looks okay to me... e.g., the last sequence $(m,m,...,m,m)$ is just the $n$-digit number $mm...mm$ in base $m+1$.

Comment: @Haran I just realized myself you were referring to the printing out of the values, so I deleted my previous comment.

Comment: @Haran Thanks, again. Note that I edited my question to include the little **C** function implementing your answer. Couldn't have been easier, and works like a charm.